# Get the wrong message installing Cordova(phonegap)

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface

I'm installing phonegap CLI(versión 3.5), when I use the next command

c:>cordova

I get the next message

*The node identifier for pb000479259 is qdmx48qcn.*

Where I'd get the command instructions.

Somebody can help me? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is type `cordova help` into your CMD prompt. This will give you the list of commands that you can use.